# 0.8.0 Gradle sync failed

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

So I'm trying to transfer to android studio but I've been getting this error all the time.
This is the only thing I'm getting in the log:

> > Error:Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0] on
> >     org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@50a8e746.
>
> Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK
>   Manager. Open Android SDK Manager

The problem is that I have android support repo installed as well as pretty much everything else so I really don't have any idea how to fix this.
I've even tried deleting the .gradle and let it download again but it didn't fix anything.

Here's my build.gradle (I did make changes to it since I was getting a build error):

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
        buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        // do not use dynamic updating.
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Android SDK:
[image: SDK]

[image: SDK 2]

Comment: did you download the libs from the sdk manager...??? try changing 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'

Comment: Open Android SDK Manager and download the updates.

Comment: @geekCode Yeah as I said everything in SDK is up to date, tried changing and I get the same error

Answer (score 6):

Don't put module-level dependencies in the `buildscript` block. The `buildscript` block is for dependencies for the build system itself, i.e. if you were adding more Gradle plugins. To add dependencies for your modules, place them in the **build.gradle** file in the module directory.

Comment: so do I just delete this dependencie? When I converted the project to gradle it was generated like this.

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to re-add it where it's needed.

Comment: how do I know where it's needed? now I'm getting an error "plugin with id android" not found"